# BroadcastReceiver->Service->Notification

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I want to start service in BroadcastReceiver (BOOT_COMPLETED) and make Notification from it.
Like this:

```
   public class AutoLoad extends BroadcastReceiver {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
            Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
            i.putExtra("screen_state", false);
            context.startService(i);
        }
    }

public class MyService extends Service {

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Notification notification = new         
    NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext()).setContentTitle("New mail from ").setContentText("Text")
            .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.btn_plus).build(); // addAction
        NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.notify(0, notification);
        return Service.START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
```

But no notification I can see. Please help!

Comment: You do not need a `Service` to raise a `Notification` -- your existing code could go directly in `onReceive()`. You are also leaking your service, which will seriously irritate users. Beyond this, do you have an activity, and have you run it? Otherwise, your manifest-registered receiver will not work.

Comment: Why you want to do this way, however you can show notification message from onReceive(). Could you explain why you need this.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
         </intent-filter>
    </activity>

Comment: <receiver android:name=".AutoLoad">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
        <service android:enabled="true" android:name=".MyService"/>

Comment: I want to do background networking that is why I use service. Isn't it correct aproach?

Answer (score 0):

You will need an `Activity` and run it at least **once** in order to be able to register to `BOOT_COMPLETED` intents.

Comment: Is it really so? Can't I start my service by BroadcastReceiver without launching Activity?